# Strange Compile error with method override

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a `ProductService` class that defines the following methods.  It doesn't work, as I will explain further below, but it gives the compile error *CS1061: 'ProductService' does not contain a definition for 'GetByid'*.  Unless I've dropped the ball on method overloading, why is the public overload of GetById not seen by other code?

```
public IEnumerable<Product> ListActiveByCatId(Guid catId) {
    return _entityContext.Products
        .Include("Category")
        .Where(p => p.Category.id == catId);
}

public Product GetById(string productId) {        
    return new Product();
}

private Product GetByid(Guid productId) {
    return _entityContext.Products.First(p => p.id == productId);
}
```

I have the following code using a `ProductService`, and the two compile errors are both on *this* call:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        var productId = Request["productId"];
        if (productId == null) {
            // TODO How to get the actual parameter, not default parameter.
            productDetailDataSource.SelectParameters["productId"].DefaultValue = DefaultProductId;
        }
        *itemTitleLabel.Text = _productService.GetByid(productId).Name;*
    }
}
```

The exact compiler error is:

> C:\SCS\Products\Details.aspx.cs(21,51):
>   error CS1061: 'ProductService' does
>   not contain a definition for 'GetByid'
>   and no extension method 'GetByid'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'ProductService' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Line 21 is the one I attempted to emphasise, i.e. the one with asterisks around it in the above calling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetByid` != `GetById`

You've got a casing issue.

Answer (score 3):

Check your casing.  I'd suggest not varying method names by case only (at least not intentionally!)

```
itemTitleLabel.Text = _productService.GetById(productId).Name;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your **`GetByid`** method is set as `private`, so it can't be accessed from outside your class.

Second, the **GetByid** method is actually not an overload of your **GetById** method, since C# is case sensitive, and both your methods name are not the same, casing considered.

Third, does `Request["productId"]` not return an **object**? If that is so, a direct type cast might not be possible, thus causing the compiler unable to find an overload of your method that takes an **object** as an input parameter.

**EDIT #1**

> C:\SCS\Products\Details.aspx.cs(21,51): error CS1061: 'ProductService' does not contain a definition for 'GetByid' and no extension method 'GetByid' accepting a first argument of type 'ProductService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The object returned by `Request["productId"]` seem to be an instance of your `ProductService` class, which value is provided to your `GetByid` method. I can't see any `GetById` method overload taking an instance of `ProductService` as an input parameter.

Perhaps the use of polymorphism might help you understand what's going on here. The `var` keyword is a placeholder for your resolved type, thus making it worth your `Request["productId"]` object type. Hence, if this object returned by this call is a `ProductService`, then `var` will be replaced by `ProductService`. Inputing this value to your call to `GetByid` makes this that an overload of `GetByid` method should accept a `ProductService` as your parameter, but there is no such overload. The default of not finding an acceptable overload, the compiler tells you that it can't resolve your method call, since it cannot find any which suits the call.

Make sure that `Request["productId"]` returns a value of an expected type, which seems to be an **int**.

I would recommend that you use the types instead of `var` whenever possible. This would have pointed you to the right source of the problem, by saying that, for example, the type `object` cannot directly be converted to `int` or something alike.

Answer (score 0):

```
var productId = Request["productId"];
```

Your variable productId might be of type `Object` and you don't have method GetById accepting object as parameter.
If so, I suggest you change line above with this one:

```
var productId = Request["productId"] as string;
```

Also, as said above check casing (GetById and GetByid)